# Start Google Chrome from WSL (Debian)

Tags: debian

I've been trying to find a way to start Google Chrome from WSL (Debian),
Chrome is installed on my Windows 10 system.

For instance by typing google chrome  in the Debian terminal.

I only find answers relating to Ubuntu / Git Bash / CMD on how to solve this.

Grateful for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can check what you have in your path by running the command echo $PATH in Debian.
If there's nothing related to Chrome there you can create an alias that leads to the path of Chrome.

I suggest you locate the directory to Chrome first and then use pwd to print the path and copy it.

Then navigate to ~, open the .bashrc file with a text editor of your choice (nano for instance)
and add the following row:

alias google="/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe"

You can replace "google" with a name of your choice, in my case the path to Google Chrome is as above but
this might be different depending on version and system so make sure to locate the correct path to Chrome based on your system.

Save your edit and you should now be able to start chrome with the command you chose.